# How to solve problems on an electron application after packaging?

Tags: electron, node-modules, electron-packager

I am developing a school card generation application. I used node js with electron to have a desktop app. To create a card, I made an html template that I dynamically modify with the student's information; then I create the image of the card with "**node-html-to-image**" which I save on the local disk.
In development when I launch the app with **"npm run start"** everything works fine.
But when I do the packaging (with **electron-builder**) and run the **.exe** file; I notice that the **"node-html-to-image"** does not work anymore, and does not send an error, nothing. I tried again with **"puppeteer"**, same result.

**Has anyone had the same issue once?**

Here is the script for **node-html-to-image** :

```
nodeHtmlToImage({
                    html: `<html>

                    </html>`,
                    content: contentArray
                  })
                    .then(() => mainWindow.webContents.send('rectoRecord', "done"))
```

Here is the script for **puppeteer** :

```
(async () => {

                    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
                    const page = await browser.newPage();
                    await page.setViewport({
                      height: 581,
                      width: 945
                    });
                    const htmlString = `<html> </html>`
                  
                  
                    // if your HTML is in memory (as a string), you load it like this:
                    page.setContent(htmlString);
                  
                    const imageBuffer = await page.screenshot({});
                  
                    await browser.close();
                  
                    // write file to disk as buffer
                    await writeFile(path.resolve(appDir, `outCard/pppppp.png`), imageBuffer);
                  
                    // convert to base64 string if you want to:
                    console.log(imageBuffer.toString('base64'));
                  })();
```